# Getting infor from same column and displaying it on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I want to find out the sum of the sales for each gender and display it on a separate column. So the Gender column has M and F, and SalesAmount has the various sales for these genders. What I'm looking for is to display Total sales for M and total Sales for F on separate columns. Can you help me with the sql code? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use case when

```
  select  sum(case when Gender='M' then sales else 0 end) as M,
  sum(case when Gender='F' then sales else 0 end) as F from table
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help,

```
 SELECT Name,Gender,sum(sales), sum(case when Gender='M' then sales else 0 end) as MaleSales,
      sum(case when Gender='F' then sales else 0 end) as FemaleSales 
      FROM table
     group by Name,Gender
```

Comment: Thanks for coming up with a solution!